# Properly terminating HTTP connection from client's side

Tags: tcp, connection

(Original title: "Weird TCP connection close behavior")

I am troubleshooting TCP connection process using Wireshark. Client opens connection to server (I tried two different servers), and starts receiving long stream of data. At some point in time client wants to stop and sends server [FIN, ACK] packet, but server does not stop sending data, it continues till its own full stream end, and then sends its own completion packet [FIN, PSH, ACK]. I figured it out keeping reading data from the client's socket after client sent FIN packet. Also, after client sent this FIN packet, its state is FIN_WAIT, thus waiting for FIN response from server...

Why servers do not stop sending data and respond to FIN packet with acknowledgment with FIN set?

I would expect, after client sends FIN packet, server will still send several packets which were on the fly before it received FIN, but not the whole pack of long data stream!

Edit: reading [this](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPConnectionTermination-2.htm) I think that web server is stuck in stage "CLOSE-WAIT: The server waits for the application process on its end to signal that it is ready to close" (third row), and its data sending process "is done" when it flushed all contents to the socket at its end, and this process can not be terminated. Weird.

**Edit1: it appears my question is a little different one. I need to totally terminate connection at client's side, so that server stops sending data, and it (server) would not go crazy about forceful termination from client's side, and aborted its data sending thread at its side being ready for next connection.**

Edit2: environment is HTTP servers.

Answer (score 2):

The client has only shutdown the connection for output, not closed it. So the server is fully entitled to keep sending.

If the client had closed the connection, it would issue an RST in response to any further data received, which would stop the server from sending any more, modulo buffering.

Comment: EJP, is closing connection this way a valid behavior for client? Do you know which consequences it may have on further _server_ operation (e.g. port reuse will cause issues)? And I would be very glad if you would detail usage of "modulo" in this context, many people are not native English speakers thus may have issue understanding the meaning :)

Comment: Perfectly valid; indeed it's the only thing the client can do. The consequence is that the server will encounter a 'connection reset by peer' and should close the socket There are no adverse consequences for ports. 'Modulo' is a shorthand for 'leaving aside'.

Comment: Thank you. I want to add my experience. If I terminate connection by just closing socket (=sending RST packet to server) I, as a client, have problems connecting to same host from same source port for some time (I did not measure, but seems it could be up to double digits of seconds).

Comment: Hang on. Closing the socket send a FIN. The RST is sent when further data arrives. You should be able to reconnect immediately, unless there is something strange about how your server is written.

Comment: I use hardware implemented stack in the device called W5100 from Korean company WIZnet. With its implementation, there's DISCON command which sends FIN (and there's a problem in its documentation regarding definitions of what happens when). Close command just frees all internal stack resources (and sends/responds with RST if needed - not sure when exactly).

Answer (score 1):

> Why servers do not stop sending data and respond to FIN packet with acknowledgment with FIN set?

Why should they? The client has said it won't send another request, but that doesn't mean it isn't interested in the response to any requests it has already sent.

Most protocols, such as HTTP, specify that the server should complete the response to the current request and only then close the connection. This is not an abnormal abort, it's just a promise not to send anything else.

Comment: Well, if client does not want to receive anything, what should it do? I do not see standard describing it. And it seems just terminating connection with close (RST) is not a valid action with predictable results at remote side? Server will keep pushing its data through, even if client is totally gone...

Comment: Ok, it is clear about promise of client. Then I need to rephrase question a little - how to totally abort connection from client's side, so that client does not receive information it does not need, but at the same time server will properly stop sending unneeded data and did not hang/go crazy?

Comment: @Anonymous That would require an agreement between the server and client to handle some particular situation in some particular way. If the protocol does not provide a way to do this, there is no way to do this. TCP doesn't specify what the client or server should do in response to particular TCP events.

Comment: David, thank you. In my case I am using HTTP servers - Apache and Nginx. Can you advise any "particular way"? I think initially my application was just closing socket, but it caused some strange problems when reconnecting to same server. Now I disconnect, but it involves whole data receive (bandwidth + time) which I want to avoid.

Comment: @Anonymous Try using `HEAD` instead of `GET`.

Comment: David, I need partial content anyway, HEAD gives just response that resource is there.

Comment: @Anonymous You should ask a new question. Explain in as much detail as you can what "strange problems" you see.

Comment: To conclude: thank you very much for your responses. Now I do not see what happens as "strange problems" as I initially thought, it works as expected... I just need to accomplish non-standard task for TCP/HTTP terminating the connection properly from client's side.